# What is the weapon wielded by the basic guard?

Tags: mirrors-edge-catalyst

Simple question, in the beta, you can fight different type of guard.
One of them is equipped with a SMG that I do not recognize, can anybody help to identify it?

Here is the official picture of the guard:

[image: KSEC Guard]

Bonus point: Is it possible to play with this weapon in any FPS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about attempting to identify a real life weapon. We're not weapon experts, nor do we recommend games that match specific criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many FPS, or shooting games in general will often use unrealistic gun attachments and guns themselves, making for it hard to set a label on just what guns are, or what they were based off of. This is especially true in Mirrors-Edge Catalyst, as it's set in a futuristic setting with advanced technology, so it's likely that guns we have *now* wouldn't match up to a gun in the present.

However, putting parts and pieces, that gun could be broken down into parts to look similar of a gun in the present.

That gun is similar to a  [Black KRISS Vector SMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KRISS_Vector), that looks like this:

[image]

This gun is nearly exact to that of the one in the picture, except that the stock (end piece that's near the character in the picture's shoulder) is placed lower, rather that above, level with the rest of the gun. The glowing object near the barrel (piece near to the character's left hand) is a miniature blue LED flashlight attached to the gun.

The KRISS Vector can in fact be found in [Call of Duty, Modern Warfare 2](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Vector) and [Battefield 4](http://bf4central.com/battlefield-4-smgs/)